# GitLab Notification Preparing Build

Tags: gitlab

We just upgrade GitLab to 8.7.3 and notice that every time we open a new MR page, it will shows a notification like this:

[image]

We are not using any CI integeration with GitLab and we don't have this notification with the previous version. Is there a way that we can disable this feature? It is very annoying to see this notification message pop up very time.

---

Edit:

As suggested by @Kai, also check the **Features** settings and we don't have **Builds** selected:

[image]

Comment: We're seeing the same problems with 8.7.4. Did you fix it?

Comment: @S0me0ne We think it is a bug in this version. We haven't found a fix for it. But this workaround works for us http://stackoverflow.com/a/37326311/1035008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notification from the gitlab is actually coming from Chrome and can be disabled here:

chrome://settings/contentExceptions#notifications

(Copy paste the above to the address bar in chrome)

[image]

The fact that it throws a notification whenever I open the MR page seems more like a bug in the new version. But the above workaround works for us.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but I would expect this not to happen if you uncheck `Builds` in the `Features` section in the Project Settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But I've checked and we don't have that *Builds* selected.